# C - write() not writing to file

Tags: c, file

My problem is simple, when i try to confirm if the function wrote on the file, nothing shows up, the file is there, but there's nothing inside the file, where should be 1024 times the string i wanted.

```
int escreve1x( const char* path , const char* cadeia )

int fd = open( path, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IXOTH );
int i;

printf("%s\n", cadeia);

for ( i=0 ; i<=1024 ; i++ )
{
    write( fd, cadeia, 10);
}

return 0 ;
```

Comment: What is the contents of `cadeia`?

Comment: where is your file stream?

Comment: What is the value of `fd`? You should probably pass `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` to `open`: "[The argument flags must include one of the following access modes: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)".

Comment: i think `O_RDWR` this is enough for read and wirte. then why all mode?

Comment: You must check errors: `fd= open(...); if (fd < 0) { perror(path); exit(1);}`

Comment: 1. `int fd = open( path, O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IXOTH );`
2. `write( fd, cadeia, strlen(cadeia));`

Comment: Leaks an fd, which is not closed.  IME, not closing a file in C, even if a write() succeeds, tends to leave a file of size 0.

Answer (score 0):

1-Add "O_RDWR" flag for making fd writable.
2-Always debug the result of write syscall;

```
int fd = open( path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IXOTH );
if(fd<0) {
printf("Open failed\n");
return 1;
}
int i;
printf("%s\n", cadeia);
for ( i=0 ; i<=1024 ; i++ ) {
int status=write( fd, cadeia, 10);
if(status<0) {
printf("Write failed");
}
}
return 0;
```

If it says write has failed then check errno.

Comment: Surely you mean `if (status < 0)`? You should also check the return value of `open`.

Comment: The file length, if the file is less than one disk block (typically 4096 bytes) will be zero unless the close(fd); is called after the writing is completed.  Even if the file is greater than a disk block, the last block to be written will not be written without either a flush(fd); or close(fd);  Not having the close(fd) results in a resource leak.